# How can I shelve changes from all users in a workspace in perforce?

Tags: perforce

P4 info:
Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2013.2/938876 (2014/09/23)

How can I shelve changes made by all users/clients of a workarea ?
I have a work model where user A creates the workspace, populates with a P4 sync, then makes some changes in the default CL.  Then user B goes to that same workarea and makes more changes.  Apparent;y "p4 shelve" will only shelve changes made by user A.  User A needs to be able to shelve his/her changes PLUS those of user B together in one shelve.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend users sharing the same workspace. That being said, you could still follow a procedure such as:

1. When finished with their work, User A shelves their files
2. When beginning their work, User B *unshelves* User A's shelved files (taking care to check the "Overwrite workspace files even if they are writable" box).
3. User B completes their work and shelves all of the files to this point.

Continue as necessary, like passing the baton in a relay race.

Comment: +1 for "wouldn't recommend users sharing the same workspace".  This shared code area should probably be a branch/stream, not a workspace.

Comment: ^^^^ *defintely* a better way to handle it!

Comment: Sharing a workspace isn't that uncommon in our business.  Different experts are sometimes asked to make special "contributions" before submit.  Update: One of the real "user A's" said that "p4 reopen -c default" put user B's changes in his default CL.  I didn't think that was possible.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not possible to separate changes to the same file in the same workspace, so yeah, that sounds about right.  Sharing a workspace does not really make sense.